# Passing multi select values to controller in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

so im trying to pass back the selected values in an array from this Kendo UI multi select

```
            @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
                .Placeholder("Select Profiles")
                .Name("Profiles")
                .Value(new[] { new { } })
                .HtmlAttributes(new
                {
                    id = "ID",
                    data_bind = "options: Profiles_msl, optionsText: 'profiles', optionsValue: 'ID'"
                })

            )
```

controller method emty

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Regen(ViewModel model, string selcteditem )
        {   
            if (ModelState.IsValid)       
            {

}

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

and this is the form header on the cshtml page

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Regen", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

This is currently saying that the object is null, Im just wanting to pass the array of selected values to the controller

any help would be good

Comment: What object is null?

Comment: the form object, I am actually confused how to send the data from my multi-select list

Comment: What form object. Do you mean its `null` in the controllers POST method - it which case show the code!

Comment: @Mich - can you add controller code?

Comment: @kamo added but tis just a empty controller with a model, its more the kendo UI and how I send it to the controller I am needing help with, I would use .DataSource and push the data to a JavaScript method, but i am binding the data via Knockout.js

Comment: Why do you have `MultiSelect` but then only allow one item? You have given the control  `name="language"` so your POST method need parameter `string[] language` in order to bind.

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry that wasn't suppose to be there, corrected

Comment: I assume your page load at first works fine and when you `submit` the page it throws a `null reference exception`? I don't know much about kendo ui, but there must be a code in your `GET` action which sets the list to `ViewBag` or `ViewData` that binds to the `Multiselect`? if so, when the `POST` action returns i.e. `return View(model);` that `model` doesn't have the list that needs to bind to `Multiselect`. why? because post action only binds the items that you have selected, not all the options available to select. You will have to re initialise the list somehow in your `POST`

Comment: @Amila thanks to StephenMuecke im now getting a array of the values, [1,2,3] ect but not the actual text but I am getting there slowly

Comment: @Mich, you specify that you want the ID with `optionsValue: 'ID'` - is you want to post back an array of the selected text values, then it needs to be `optionsValue: 'profiles'`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks iv figured it all out now anyway and ti was mainly due to your help so thanks :)